# How to make ViewGroup translucent (NOT transparent)

Tags: android, android-resources, android-viewgroup, android-color

I found a description about the difference of transparent and translucent. These are the important parts:

> **What does translucent mean?** If you were writing about a pane of glass,
> but that pane of glass was frosty, darkly colored, or very dirty, you
> would use translucent.
>
> **What does transparent mean?** If you were writing about a pane of glass,
> and that piece of glass was perfectly clear, you would use
> transparent. Something that is transparent allows all light to pass
> through it. Clean air and the windshield of a car are transparent.

If you want to understand this deeply then look [here](https://writingexplained.org/translucent-vs-transparent-difference).

I want to make a ViewGroup translucent in Android. In a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KN1b4Xv4_w) I found how to make an **Activity** translucent. What they do is defining the following styles and colors:

```
<color name="transparent_green_color">#8800ff00</color>

<style name="TranslucentGreen" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_green_color</item>
</style>
```

And then in the manifest the within the application tag they add this new style as a theme:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/TranslucentGreen"
    ...>
...
</application>
```

What I want to do is **NOT** to make an `Activity` translucent but to make a `ViewGroup` translucent.

My layout is structured like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The second `RelativeLayout` shall be translucent and the first one shall be visible a bit through the translucent `RelativeLayout`. How to do that?

Comment: Please take the important content from the links and put it in your question. People shouldn't have to read whole article or watch a youtube video to understand your question

Comment: You would need to use a translucent Png image as background, because with the help of color code you can only set transparency

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ I updated it and still kept the links but I added a short description what they do in these pages. Should now be easy to read.

Comment: @Mayur: So you would add a translucent png as background to the second ``RelativeLayout``? Wouldn't that completely overlay the first one so that it is not visible through the "glass"?

Comment: @thepatel no if the png is translucent than it would let the layout behind it be visible through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) library solved my problem. So if the second ViewGroup (in my case second `RelativeLayout`) has to be at the top and the first one has to shine through translucent, then you need to call something like:

```
Blurry.with(context).radius(25).sampling(2).onto(viewGroup);
```

and then you have the desired effect. For going back to the old view state **without** translucency you can just use this method:

```
Blurry.delete(viewGroup)
```

on the desired view. I like that library because it's very compact.

---

If you are not able to use external libraries you should maybe start with [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-blur-effect-on-android-with-renderscript-aa05dae0bd7d). It works with [RenderScript](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) and [Bitmap class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html). Bu It shall be possible to create Bitmaps from ViewGroups.

Comment: It would be nice to show how this could be accomplished without the use of external libraries. Some readers may not be able to add blurry as a dependency and don't understand how views can have a simple background color or png with an alpha.

Comment: @petey Ok I added a small hint but I cannot dive deep into it. I hope it helps.

Comment: I was thinking something as easy as, `<RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/my_translucent_bg">`.  What you have is much harder approach and likely not worthwhile to perform.

Comment: @petey Maybe Mayur's approach is working. I didn't try that with a translucent png background. But if you have another approach for that please tell me.